# On the proof that $4$-velocity transforms like vector

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, vectors, inertial-frames, mathematics

Let $U$ and $U'$ be the $4$-velocities associated to the coordinates $(t,x)$ and $(t',x')$ related through the Poincaré transformation $P:\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^4$, i.e. $(t',x')=P(t,x)$.$^1$

Of course the Jacobian $\Lambda\in\mathbb R^{4\times 4}$ of $P$ is a Lorentz transformation. I extracted the following derivation of the tranformation rule for $U$ from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208090/237923):
\begin{equation}
U'=\frac{\mathrm dX'}{\mathrm d\tau}=\frac{\mathrm d(P\circ X)}{\mathrm d\tau}=\Lambda\cdot\frac{\mathrm d X}{\mathrm d\tau}=\Lambda\cdot U\in\mathbb R^{4\times 1}
\end{equation}
As far as I understand, we used the fact that
\begin{equation}
\forall \tau:X'(\tau)=(P\circ X)(\tau),
\end{equation}
but this is not trivial, is it? I will explain my reasoning and I hope for a confirmation/verification:

We have $X(\tau):=X(t(\tau))$, where $I\ni t\mapsto X(t)$ is the $4$-position and $\tau\mapsto t(\tau)$ is the inverse of proper time, i.e. the inverse of the function
$\newcommand{\d}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}$
\begin{align}
I\ni t\mapsto \tau(t)=\int_{t_0}^t\sqrt{1-\frac{v(\widetilde t)^2}{c^2}}\d\widetilde t+c
\end{align}
for some $t_0\in I$ and $c\in\mathbb R$. So what we are really assuming is the following:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
X'\circ t'=P\circ X\circ t
\end{equation}
Let $\Pi:\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R$ be the projection to the time component, then $X'=P\circ X\circ(\Pi\circ P\circ X)^{-1}$ and hence $(1)$ follows from the fact that
\begin{equation}
t'=\Pi\circ P\circ X\circ t
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\tau=\tau'\circ\Pi\circ P\circ X
\end{equation}
and which can be proven through a change of variables.$^2$ Am I right?

---

$^1$ The reader familiar with manifolds will note that $(t,x)$ is a chart $\phi: M\to\mathbb R^4$ and that $P=\phi'\circ\phi^{-1}$.

$^2$ We are exploiting the fact that $\tau$ and $\tau'$ are only defined up to a constant when we assume that $t$ and $t'$ have the same domains.

Comment: Related : [Transformation of  4− velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/460934/transformation-of-4-velocity/470031#470031).

Comment: @Frobenius I think your answer boils down to the same problem: In equation $(17)$, you have implicitly defined $t′(t):=(\Pi\circ P\circ X)(t)$, so we have two functions denoted by $t′$, namely $t′(t)$ and $t′(\tau)$. In equation $(18)$, when you write
$$\frac{\mathrm dt'}{\mathrm d\tau}\boldsymbol{=}\frac{\mathrm dt'}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm d\tau}$$
you are implicitly assuming that $t′=t′\circ t$, which is equivalent to the last equation in my question. Do we agree?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean and why you try to prove a simple case by a high level complex elaboration. Note also that the velocity 4-vector $\:\mathbf U\:$ is a Lorentz one as the ratio of the Lorentz position  differential 4-vector  $\:\mathrm d\mathbf X\:$ and the scalar Lorentz invariant differential of the proper time $\:\mathrm d\tau\:$  $$\mathbf U=\dfrac{\mathrm d\mathbf X}{\mathrm d\tau}$$

Comment: @Frobenius "Note also..." - I think that's essentially the first equation in my question, isn't it? As I have explained in my answer, I think that the proof is not quite complete: We are implicitly using that $t'=\Pi\circ P\circ X\circ t$. Your proof is a bit different, but as I explained in my first comment I think that you are implicitly using $t'=\Pi\circ P\circ X\circ t$, too.

Comment: ...charts, domains, Jacobians, Poicare, manifolds, projection to the time component etc. If in the past I had try to understand a little of  Special Relativity starting with all these I would quit my hobby to learn Physics asap.

Comment: I apologize, but I am unable to help you even a little with your problem (which moreover I don't understand at all).

Comment: @Frobenius I should have formulated the problem without using charts (I have edited the question in the meantime). $\Pi:\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R$ is simply defined by $\Pi(t,x)=t$. My point is that if I recall the transformation formula for world lines$$X'=P\circ X\circ(\Pi\circ P\circ X)^{-1}$$and the definition of proper time, then I think that it is not so obvious that$$X'\circ t'=P\circ X\circ t$$holds.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making this unnecessarily difficult. Here is a proof.
$$
U = \lim_{\delta\tau \rightarrow 0} \frac{X(t+\delta\tau) - X(t)}{\delta\tau}
$$
Now use that $\delta\tau$ is invariant and the difference of two 4-vectors evaluated at a given event is itself a 4-vector (which is easy to prove). It follows that $U$ is a 4-vector multiplied by a scalar invariant, hence it is a 4-vector.

Comment: "Now use that $\delta\tau$ is invariant" - Isn't that precisely what I am trying to prove through a change of variables? To be precise, we have that$$\forall t_1,t_2\in I:\tau(t_1)-\tau(t_2)=(\tau'\circ\Pi\circ P\circ X)(t_2)-(\tau'\circ\Pi\circ P\circ X)(t_1),$$don't we?

Comment: @Filippo    Why prove something that is a fundamental assumption of SR? Such things seem more like a mathematical exercise than physics.

Comment: @jellyears The point is that we **can** prove this (i.e. this is not an additional assumption). Of course you can skip the proof :) But I consider the proof instructive: You have to use integration by substitution and the fact that the metric is invariant under Lorentz transformations.

Answer (score 0):

As @Frobenius said in the comments, this is a bit too complex to understand a relatively easy equation. I would like to make your equations  bit clearer here.

As you said, $X'(t)=(P\circ X)(\tau)$ should actually be:

$$(X'\circ t')(\tau)=(P\circ X)(\tau)$$

Then, applying inverse function on the right:

$$(X'\circ t' \circ (t')^{-1})(\tau)=(P\circ X \circ (t')^{-1})(\tau)$$

$$(X')(\tau)=(P\circ X \circ (t')^{-1})(\tau)$$

Using the projection operator:

$$(\tau)=(\Pi \circ P\circ X \circ (t')^{-1})(\tau)$$

Why? Because $(X' \circ t')(\tau) \ne (X \circ t')(\tau)$. Therefore applying  $(\Pi \circ X')(\tau) \ne (t')(\tau)$. By the way, in my definition projection operation is something that takes out the first component of a vector. And $X'$ is just a function that is different from $X$.

So I would summarize this redundant set of operations as the following:

1. Take proper time and apply an inverse transform on it which is just the inverse of the operation that a Lorentz boost would do on the proper time.
2. Use this as an argument of your 4-position vector.
3. Apply the Lorentz boost.
4. Take the projection in time.

Voilà! You are at the very same time where you started.

Comment: "As you said..." - I don't think that I said that.